# Tengo un problema al insertar imagenes y datos en mysql al mismo tiempo con AJAX y php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, formularios

Veran estoy haciendo una pagina de productos y necesito insertar los datos como su nombre, descripcion etc en una tabla, e insertar en otra tabla sus imagenes, necesito primero insertar los datos y despues las imagenes para poder obtener el id del producto y poder hacer una conexion entre las imagenes y el producto, el problema es que no logro obtener la informacion del producto escrita en el formulario pero si las imagenes que subi.
Este es el codigo que me insertaba solo las imagenes en la tabla, lo del id no hay problema, el problema esta en que no logro obtener la informacion del formulario y pasarla a php mediante ajax

Este es el formulario

```
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload-multi-images">
            <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Price</label>
                    <input type="text" name="price" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Stock</label>
                    <input type="text" name="stock" class="form-control" required autocomplete="off">
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xl-2 col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-12" id="add-photo-container">
                        <div class="add-new-photo first" id="add-photo">
                            <span><i class="icon-camera"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="file" multiple id="add-new-photo">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="button-container">
                    <button type="submit">Subir imágenes</button>
                </div> 
            </form>
```

Este es el codigo de AJAX para mandar los datos a php

```
var formData = new FormData();
$(document).on("change", "#add-new-photo", function () {

    var files = this.files;
    var element;
    var supportedImages = ["image/jpeg", "image/png", "image/gif"];
    var seEncontraronElementoNoValidos = false;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        element = files[i];
        
        if (supportedImages.indexOf(element.type) != -1) {
            var id = getRandomString(7);
            createPreview(element, id);
            formData.append(id, element);
            
        }
        else {
            seEncontraronElementoNoValidos = true;
        }
    }
    
    if (seEncontraronElementoNoValidos) {
        showMessage("Se encontraron archivos no validos.");
    }
    else {
        showMessage("Todos los archivos se subieron correctamente.");
    }

});
$(document).on("submit", "#upload-multi-images", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    //Envio mediante Ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "upload.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        beforeSend: function () {
            loading(true, "Subiendo foto...");
        },
        success: function (res) {
            loading(false);
            if (res.status == "true") {
                createImages(res.all_ids);
                $("#Images form .row > div:not(#add-photo-container)").remove();
                formData = new FormData();
            } else {
                alert(res.error);
            }
        },
        error: function (e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });

});
```

Y este es el php con el que lo inserto en la base datos

```
if (isset($_FILES) && !empty($_FILES)) {
$files = array_filter($_FILES, function($item) {
    return $item["name"][0] != "";
});

foreach ($files as $file) {
    $tmp_name = $file["tmp_name"];
    $name = $file["name"];
    $path = "/images/$name";
    $pathSYS = "/var/www/html/images/$name";
    $insertImages = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO product_files (id_pro, name, web_path, system_path) VALUES (:idPRO, :name, :path, :pathSYS)");
    $wasUploaded = $insertImages->execute(array(
        ":name" => $name,
        ":idPRO" => $idPRO,
        ":path" => $path,
        ":pathSYS" => $pathSYS,
    ));

    if ($wasUploaded) {
        $id = $conexion->lastInsertId();
        $data["all_ids"]["id_$id"]["id"] = $id;
        $data["all_ids"]["id_$id"]["name"] = $name;
        move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "images/$name");
    }
    else {
        die("Hubo un error, por favor, contacta al administrador.");
    }
}
```

}

Agradeceria muchisimo su ayuda, soy un programador novato y no he podido continuar mi proyecto por culpa de ese error, Espero y me puedan ayudar, muchas gracias

Comment: Hola Sebastián, la pregunta está planteada de una forma confusa. No se entiende exactamente cuál es el problema, ¿podrías exponerlo lo más sencillamente posible, para luego poder revisar el código? Si te da algún error, agrégalo a la pregunta y explica también cuál es el resultado del código y qué esperas obtener, qué has depurado y con qué resultados.

Comment: Tiene razon me exprese un poco mal. Tengo 2 tablas en mysql, una que es donde va la informacion de los productos y otra donde va las imagenes de dichos productos, las imagenes estan conectadas mediante el id del producto que es autoincrementable. Lo que quiero hacer es insertar la informacion del producto en su respectiva tabla y despues insertar las imagenes en su respectiva tabla obteniendo el id del producto insertado, el problema es que quiero hacer esto al mismo tiempo, es decir hacer las 2 inserciones cuando le pulse el boton de enviar.

Comment: Hasta el momento he logrado hacer lo que quiero, que es insertar las imagenes y la informacion al mismo tiempo, pero la informacion la tuve que declarar en el archivo php, no he conseguido obtener lo que digito en el formulario. En si ese es el problema que tengo, al no poder insertar la informacion obtenida del formulario no puedo insertar las imagenes.